# Django Model Forms set possible values of foreign key dropdown

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form `ReviewForm` that extends `ModelForm`. `ReviewForm`'s model is `Review`, which has the fields:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length = 4000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(
        default = 5, 
        validators = [MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(0)]
    )
    prof = models.ForeignKey(Prof, related_name = 'reviews')
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name = 'reviews')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'reviews')
```

and for `forms.py`

```
class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
    rating = CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'type': 'number','value': 5, 'min': 0, 'max': 5}))

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['message', 'rating', 'prof', 'course', 'user']
```

I'm trying to pass initial values to the form before rendering it. Here's my code for `views.py`

```
def review(request, prof_id=None):
    """ Review a prof """
    # If there's an input prof, return review page for that prof
    if prof_id:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        prof = prof_views.prof(prof_id)
        course = prof.course_set.all()
        data = {'user': user, 'prof': prof, 'course': course}
        review_form = ReviewForm(initial=data)

        return render(request, 'reviews/review_form.html', {'review_form': review_form})
    review_form = ReviewForm()
    return render(request, 'reviews/review_form.html', {'review_form': review_form})
```

The initial values of `prof` and `user` are set successfully. I'm trying to pass in the `courses` of a `prof`, and have the form display that queryset. However, Django doesn't seem to accept it.

I'm not sure how to code this function. Setting the initial value of `prof` and `user` works because it selects the initial value. I'm sure that the code to get a prof's courses: `course = prof.course_set.all()` works properly, I've tested it in shell. So what I need to do is set the *possible* values of the form's courses, based on the queryset input.

Comment: What do yo mean by "Django doesn't seem to accept it. "? Are you expecting to be rendered a dropdown but it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @solarissmoke for the link! I fixed it with:

```
def review(request, prof_id=None):
    """ Review a prof """
    # If there's an input prof, return review page for that prof
    if prof_id:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        prof = prof_views.prof(prof_id)
        course = prof.course_set.all()
        data = {'user': user, 'prof': prof}
        review_form = ReviewForm(initial=data)
        review_form.fields['course'].queryset = course  # Added this line
```